# Probability notation with and without condition

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-probability

If I have an information I which is true for assumption, is it correct to write both $P(I | I) = P(I)$ or is it always necessary to specify the condition?

Comment: P(I|I) is certain (=1), because I is always true when you assume I, so it's not the same as P(I).

Answer (score 1):

From the definition of conditional probability:

$$
P(I|I) = \frac{P(I\cap I)}{P(I)} = \frac{P(I)}{P(I)} = 1
$$

Conditional probability and probability are two different objects so we must be careful with the notation. If you assume that the event I will occur with probability 1, the equality that you wrote is true.